# What is difference between two strings?

Tags: encoding

- %EB%AA%A8%EB%85%B8%EA%B0%80%ED%83%80%EB%A6%AC
- %B8%F0%B3%EB%B0%A1%C5%B8%B8%AE

I decode them. and They are same as "모노가타리". But their encoded appearance are different. I think they have different encoding.

What is difference between two strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first encoding is UTF-8. The second appears to be Unified Hangeul.

http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/encoding.php?name=Unified+Hangeul&char=B8F0